# The removeItem function is not removing item in my toDO List in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [item, setItem] = useState("")
const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([])
const [actualItem, setActualItem] = useState([])

function addItem(){
    setItemList([...itemList , item])
    setActualItem([...itemList , item])
    setItem("")
}

function filterVal(e){
    const filteredArr = itemList.filter((item)=> item.includes(e.target.value))
    if (filteredArr.length !== 0 && e.target.value.length > 3) {
        setItemList(filteredArr)    
    } else {
        setItemList(actualItem)
    }
}

console.log("render")

function removeItem(e){
    const val = itemList.indexOf(e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText)
    itemsArr = itemList 
    itemsArr.splice(val, 1)
    console.log(itemsArr)
    setItemList(itemsArr)
}

return (
    <div className="body">
        <div className="search">
        <input type="text" onChange={filterVal} placeholder="Search Here"/>
    </div>
    <div className="addItem">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add here" value={item} onChange={(e)=>{setItem(e.target.value)}}/>
        <button className="btn" onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
        <ul className="display">
            {
                itemList.length === 0 ? <h1>No Items</h1> : 
                itemList.map((item, index)=>{
                    return (
                        <div className="li" key={index} id={index}>
                            <li>{item}</li>
                            <p onClick={removeItem}>✖</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                }
        </ul>
        <button className="clearBtn" onClick={()=>{setItemList([]); setActualItem([])}}>Clear All</button>
    </div>
    </div>
)
```

I am building a todo list using react. Adding, clear all and search functionality are working fine. But the removeItem is not working. When i click on the cross button, it should splice the array of items and update the actual state. But it is not. The state is updating but it is not getting reflected in the map function

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost working, but the issue happens at how JS compares objects/arrays.

In your `removeItem` method, you have the right thinking to copy the value of the state `itemList` to a temporary value `itemArr`. HOWEVER, what you did here is actually copied the reference/address of the `itemList`, and is mutating it directly (which is a bad practice, but you had the right idea according to how you code, so thumbs up for that).

When the state is updated in `setItemList(itemsArr)`, React makes a comparison of the state's `itemList`, turns out the value that you have previously passed in in `setItemList` is exactly the same!

(See "Referential Equality" section of this article for more info https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/#1-referential-equality)

What you are supposed to do is, declare a new variable, COPY the value of the `itemList` instead of the reference, run your logic, then finally set the state with `setItemList(itemsArr);` so React will realize that the value of the state `itemList` has actually been updated, and finally cause a rerender, updating the UI.

This is the fix to your `removeItem` method --

```
  function removeItem(e) {
    const val = itemList.indexOf(
      e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText
    );
    const itemsArr = [...itemList]; // <-- this is important part
    itemsArr.splice(val, 1);
    console.log(itemsArr);
    setItemList(itemsArr);
  }
```

See your work in action in CodeSandbox -- https://codesandbox.io/s/great-marco-f4pkd5?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Ref: https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const ref = useRef("");
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  const [actualItem, setActualItem] = useState([]);

  function addItem() {
    const item = ref.current.value;
    setItemList([...itemList, item]);
    setActualItem([...itemList, item]);
    ref.current.value = '';
  }

  function filterVal(e) {
    const filteredArr = itemList.filter((item)=> item.includes(e.target.value));

  
  if (filteredArr.length !== 0 && e.target.value.length > 3) {
    setItemList(filteredArr);
  } else {
    setItemList(actualItem);
  }
}

function removeItem(e) {
  const val = itemList.indexOf(
    e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText
  );
  const itemsArr = [...itemList];
  itemsArr.splice(val, 1);
  console.log(itemsArr);
  setItemList(itemsArr);
}

return (
  <div className="body">
    <div className="search">
      <input type="text" onChange={filterVal} placeholder="Search Here" />
    </div>
    <div className="addItemcc">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add here" ref={ref} />
      <button className="btn" onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
      <ul className="display">
        {
          itemList.length === 0 ? <h1>No Items</h1> :
            itemList.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="li" key={index} id={index}>
                  <li>{item}</li>
                  <p onClick={removeItem}>✖</p>
                </div>
              )
            })
        }
      </ul>
      <button className="clearBtn" onClick={() => { setItemList([]); setActualItem([]) }}>Clear All</button>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code instead

```
const removeItem = (e) => {
        const val = itemList.indexOf(e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText)
        setItemList(itemList.filter(item => item !== val)
    
}
```

Comment: Still not working. The itemList state is not getting updated

Comment: I believe this line should be 
 <p onClick={() => removeItem(item)}>✖</p>